# Why does vsnwprintf not translate normal strings to wide strings?

Tags: c++, c

The following code does not produce the expected output. Why?

```
    wchar_t* wchar_t_printf_return(wchar_t* formatstring, ...){
        va_list argp;
        va_start(argp, formatstring);
        int templen = 256;
        templen = vsnwprintf(NULL, 0, formatstring, argp)+3;
        wchar_t *buffer = (wchar_t *) malloc ((templen+1)*sizeof(wchar_t));
        memset(buffer, 0, (templen+1)*sizeof(*buffer));
        int retval;
        while ((retval = vsnwprintf(buffer, templen, formatstring, argp)) == -1 || (retval >= (templen-1))){
            templen = templen << 1;
            buffer = (wchar_t *) realloc (buffer, (templen+1)*sizeof(wchar_t));
            va_end(argp);
            va_start(argp, formatstring);
        }
        va_end(argp);
        buffer[templen] = L'\0';
        return buffer;
    }

    int main(){
        int i;
        char *id = "2923BE84E16CD6AE529049F1F1BBE9EB";
        wchar_t *val = wchar_t_printf_return(L"'%s'", id);
        printf("%ls\n", val);
    }
```

EDIT: to state more specifically, the printf in main should wrap the id in two single quotes thereby outputting: '2923BE84E16CD6AE529049F1F1BBE9EB'. The purpose of the main here is to illustrate the bug in the function, no more. The function is supposed to be an alternate of the printf family functions which return the result in a newly allocated buffer instead of a preexisting one. This is being run in cygwin compiled natively via gcc-3 with the -mno-cygwin option (aka mingw). Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: It might help if you included the rest of your function so it could include what gets returned. It also might help if you include a) what gets returned in a simple case (such as replacing your `id` with something trivial) and b) what you expected to be returned.

Comment: Nasty code; nasty question. It would help if you gave us the unexpected output and also the expected output ... !

Comment: Looks like a mess - what is that function supposed to do?

Comment: Works fine for me once I replace your fictitious `vsnwprintf` by the standard library function [`vswprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wprintf). Make sure to include `<wchar.h>`, `<string.h>`, and `<std{io,lib,arg}.h>`. Using GCC 4.6.1. (Note: You should probably call `setlocale("")` before any of this!!)

Comment: Yea, I cant find documentation of the function anywhere! I had to actually find the function itself by digging through the system headers. The standard version doesnt exist in mingw under cygwin for some reason.

Comment: Hm. In general, the `w`-printing function should call `mbctowc()` for `%s` arguments, and the narrow printing function should call `wctombc()` for `%Ls` arguments (hence the need for `setlocale("");`!), so this *should* work. It might be a flaw in MingW, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%s` specifier changes meaning depending on whether you are using a `printf` or `wprintf` family function. [When used with a `wprintf` family function, the `%s` specifier indicates a wide string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hf4y5e3w%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), but you're passing a narrow string. You need `%hs` to say "This is a narrow string."

(You seemed to be aware of this because you use `%ls` to print a wide string with a `printf`-family function, but you somehow forgot about it when going the other way.)

Comment: Works now, I accidentally erased the cast to wide string. Thanks!

Comment: @Raymond: Is this part of the C standard, or a Microsoft quirk?

Comment: Unclear what "this" refers to, but either way, you can go consult the standard yourself.

Comment: I checked with the C99 standard, and that behaviour is a clear violation. The standard demands that a `%s`-argument be interpreted as a `char*`. In the `printf` case no further assumption is made; in the `wprintf` case, the pointer is supposed to point to a convertible multibyte sequence (to be fed into `mbrtowc()`).

Comment: You're right, this appears to be a Microsoft quirk. That's probably why the Microsoft version of `_vnswprintf` begins with an underscore, to highlight that it's nonstandard.

Answer (score 1):

Try using %S for a translation, not %s.